# When JButton Disable, the text shown in JButton(for some selected)

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I want to hide the text in JButton. When User click the JButton, the text will display.

This the the requirement for my game(user need find the "hit" in those button):
http://gyazo.com/73475fc9725bbc750463dbefc55d55ad

Now my code is displaying this way(I want them hide inside the button)
http://gyazo.com/d7ac57eb287aa8601067b87d0755cfc9

---

Random class:

```
for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) {
        int randomThree = new java.util.Random().nextInt(gridNo);
        int randomThree2 = new java.util.Random().nextInt(gridNo);
        if (ButtonArray[randomThree][randomThree2].getText() != "hit") { 
            // to prevent have same position hit
            ButtonArray[randomThree][randomThree2].setText("hit");

        }
```

Main Class: Button Action:

```
            ButtonArray[row][col].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    ButtonArray[r][c].setEnabled(false); 

                    if ( ButtonArray[r][c].getText().equalsIgnoreCase("hit")) {
                        game.incCountHit(1);
                        if (game.getCountHit() == 3) {
                            startBtn.setText("Restart Game "); // set text
                        }
                    }
                }
            });randHit.randomNo();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put this code on the click event of the button you intend to show the desired text.

Although your purpose isn't very much clear, I guess you need this:

```
    if(jButton1.isEnabled()==false){
        jButton1.setText("HIT");
    }
```

Edit as per your code:

Initially set the button's foreground color same as the button's background color.

```
    if ( ButtonArray[r][c].getText().equalsIgnoreCase("hit")) {
        game.incCountHit(1);
        ButtonArray[r][c].setForeground(Color.black);
        if (game.getCountHit() == 3) {
             startBtn.setText("Restart Game "); // set text
        }

    }
```

**Edit**:

Assume a new array for storing the text with the desired rowSize and colSize which will be same as ButtonArray.

```
String[][] newArray = new String [rowSize][colSize];
```

**Random class**:

```
 for (int y = 0; y < x; y++) {
    int randomThree = new java.util.Random().nextInt(gridNo);
    int randomThree2 = new java.util.Random().nextInt(gridNo);
    if (newArray[randomThree][randomThree2] != "hit") { 

        newArray[randomThree][randomThree2]="hit";

    }
 }
```

**Main Class: Button Action:**

```
        ButtonArray[row][col].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                ButtonArray[r][c].setEnabled(false); 

                if ( newArray[r][c].equalsIgnoreCase("hit")) {
                    game.incCountHit(1);
                    if (game.getCountHit() == 3) {
                        startBtn.setText("Restart Game "); // set text
                    }
                }
            }
        });randHit.randomNo();
```

Comment: How is the clock event meant to be triggered if the button is disabled?

Comment: I actually want the text hide in the button.
The button won't display any text first(the text only appear when the user click the right button that contain "hit")

Comment: For hiding the text, set the button's foreground(text) color to be the same as button. Change its foreground color to black when it is clicked.

Comment: @KunjanThadani however the text somehow can be seen even set Jbutton default color

Comment: Well, in such case like minesweeper you need to store the values in a separate array corresponding to the button. Or you can use image icon.

Comment: an array to store the random number?
So in the random class I should create a new array. Then put that array match with the ButtonArray?

Comment: No. Create a new array for storing the text like "hit". The new array would be of same rows and columns as the ButtonArray. Also, each element of the new array would contain text say "hit"  corresponding to ButtonArray element. Example: If ButtonArray[1][2] is clicked, then it will have a corresponding text array element as newArray[1][2], which may then contain the text "hit". So instead of setting text in a button, you would then store it in that new array element.

Answer (score 0):

For something like mind sweeper, you'd something like two arrays, one is the button array and one is "content" array.

One a button is triggered/pressed, you would determine the index in the button array of the button that was pressed and using that index, look up the "content" array for the buttons content.

You would then set the buttons text to the value of text of the given element in the "content" array.

A simpler solution would be to use some kind of `Map` keyed to the `JButton` which contained the value for that button, it would make looking up the value easier.

Comment: Sorry, I still not get what you mean

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem entirely, are you trying to do something like a mine sweeper game?

Comment: Yes. Like Mine sweeper game!